# Configure TPH Discriminator column in code first EF 4.1 using attributes

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first

I have a .NET code first EF 4.1 set of objects that I am configuring with attributes.

I would like to rename the column used as the discriminator for my Type-Per-Hierarchy inheritance and also control the values of the discriminator column.

I've seen examples of how to do this with fluent mapping, but since I am using attributes everywhere else, I'd like to be consistent and configure it using attributes.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to do that with attributes.